# Call jquery alert only when an error occured during submit

Tags: php, jquery, html

I I have a small script that will display error inside a div when an error occured in a form.

//php

```
if(empty($date_from) && empty($date_to))
{
    $error = "No search query";

}
elseif(empty($date_from) && !empty($date_to))
{
    $error = "Specify your end date search";
}
elseif(!empty($date_from) && empty($date_to))
{
    $error ="Specify your start date search";
}
else
{
    $error ="som error";
}
```

//form

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="from_date" id="field1"></p>
<p>To</p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="to_date" id="field2"></p><br />
```

//script

```
<script>
window.setTimeout(function() {
$("#alert").fadeTo(800, 0).slideUp(900, function(){
$(this).remove(); 
});
}, 3000);
</script>
```

this will automatically display error during refresh or every time the page is reloaded.What I want is to show only errors after  the user submits the button, and when an error occured.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you would expect the code you gave us to do much of anything. Use AJAX if you want to test the form errors Server Side, as well as Client Side.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your conditions in here

```
if( isset($_POST['SubmitButtonName']) ) {
    // IF ELSE STATEMENTS FOR ERROR HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it following 
php

```
if(empty($date_from) && empty($date_to))
{
    $error = "No search query";
      $iserror=1;

}
elseif(empty($date_from) && !empty($date_to))
{
    $error = "Specify your end date search";
    $iserror=1;
}
elseif(!empty($date_from) && empty($date_to))
{
    $error ="Specify your start date search";
     $iserror=1;
}
else
{
    $error ="som error";
     $iserror=1;
}







<?php
if($iserror==1 ){
?>

<script>
window.setTimeout(function() {
$("#alert").fadeTo(800, 0).slideUp(900, function(){
$(this).remove(); 
});
}, 3000);
</script>


<?php
}
```